# "How Internet helps you?" vs "How does Internet help you?"

Tags: questions, definite-article, grammatical-number, do-support

Which one of the following sentences is correct:

> "How Internet helps you?"
>
> "How does Internet help you?"

Is it always mandatory to use *"do"* in how-questions?

Comment: "How does the internet help you?" It is not mandatory to have 'do' in your 'how' questions, such as "How can I help you?"

Comment: Incidentally, I don't see that this question is getting better answers here than it did in ELU.

Comment: related ?: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17778/how-it-works-vs-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 4):

OP's example **Internet** (*without* the definite article) is a distracting non-standard usage. See [*“I don't have internet” vs. “I don't have the internet”*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124849/i-dont-have-internet-vs-i-dont-have-the-internet) as previously asked on ELU for further discussion of this).

So to focus on the *specific* aspect of usage being asked about here (using "do" to frame a question), let's change it to...

> 1: *How Facebook helps you*
>    2: *How does Facebook help you?*

Notice that in my amended version, I've removed the question mark from #1. That's because it's *not a question*. It's not even a *sentence* - it's just a [*noun phrase*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/noun-phrase). We can see this by considering...

> *Quantum physics **is** a complex subject* (Noun Phrase + **Verb** + Noun Phrase)
>    *He **explains** quantum physics*  (Pronoun + **Verb** + Noun Phrase)
>    *He **explains** how Facebook helps you*  (Pronoun + **Verb** + Noun Phrase)

---

As to whether it's *necessary* to include ***do*** in questions, consider [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/17796/126) to the earlier ELL question *“How it works?” vs. “How does it work?”*. Effectively it's *not*, since these are all valid questions...

> *How can Facebook help you?*
>    *How will Facebook help you?*
>    *How could Facebook help you?*
>    *How has Facebook helped you?*
>    *How is Facebook helping you?*
>    etc., etc.

That's to say, the *interrogative* (*how*, in this case) must be followed by an [*auxiliary verb*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/auxiliary-verb), but there are many others besides ***to do*** that can perform this function in questions.

Answer (score 4):

Of the two examples you quote:

> A1) <strike>How the Internet helps you?</strike>
>
> A2) How does the Internet help you? *(subject-operator inversion)*

only A2 is correct. Questions like A2 require what is known as a **subject-operator inversion**. In this case the subject is *the Internet* and the operator is *does*. It is called an inversion, because in English a subject usually precedes a verb.

Although subject-operator inversions are frequent in interrogative sentences, there are cases where this inversion doesn't happen. For example:

- **Wh-questions where the wh-word is the subject**

  *Who are you?*

  *What is causing that racket?*
- **Declarative questions** are questions used to ask for a confirmation, e.g.:

  A: *She quit her job?*

  B: *Yes, she did! I couldn't believe it either.*
- **Dependent interrogative clauses**
  It is possible to rephrase a question so that it becomes a dependent clause. When this happens the subject-operator inversion disappears:

  *I'm asking how the Internet helps you. Could you explain it to me?*

Comment: Also called *subject-auxiliary inversion*.  By the way, I suggest writing *the Internet* rather than just *Internet*.  (And I've personally given up on capitalizing *internet*, though I won't object if you keep doing it.)

Answer (score 2):

"How does the Internet help you?"

As there is only one Internet, you need the definite article "the" in front of it.

You do not need to always use "do" with a "how" question. You could, for example, ask, "How is the Internet helpful to you?" or "How can the Internet help you?" or "How long has the Internet existed?" "How do/does" questions ask in what manner one performs some task or the manner in which something is affected. I'm not sure that I could catalog all the types of things you could ask with "how", but that's only one of them.

Comment: I can't agree that flip *"there is only one Internet"* explanation. There's only one Facebook too, but whereas you can *find someone on **the** Internet* and *find them on Facebook*, you wouldn't normally switch usage of the definite article with either of those. When this question was originally posted on ELU it should have been closed as a duplicate of [*“I don't have internet” vs. “I don't have the internet”?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124849/), not migrated here.

Comment: That's not the reason to use do, either. One uses do whenever a construction (like a question or a negative) requires an auxiliary verb but there is none. You go get one, and the one that's available free of charge is _do_. It has no meaning and is merely holding open the First Auxiliary Verb slot so that the rule that swaps the Subject and the First Auxiliary Verb can operate. Otherwise there'd be nothing to indicate it's a question.

Comment: @John: It seems to me that in *"How does this help?"*, the verb **to do** does indeed "have no meaning", which is why non-native speakers are prone to omitting it completely. But in *"Does this help?"*, it *does* mean something. Admittedly not much, since in casual conversational contexts it's often "destressed/elided" to *"D'zis help?"*, and the initial /d/ may be discarded completely - even though in the speaker's *mind*, he probably still thinks he's including the word "does" simply because he says /z/ rather than /th/ (apologies for not doing the IPA thingy properly! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers RE "the Internet". Fair enough. The difference is whether a word is viewed as a name, or as a title or description. We don't use articles with proper names, like we don't say, "I gave it to the Fred Smith." We do use "the" with titles and descriptive terms, like, "I gave it to the assistant manager". So a more complete answer would include that "Internet" is viewed as a title or descriptive term and not a proper name. Of course here I'm talking in circles. Why do we use "the"? Because it's a title. How do we know it's a title? Because we always use it with "the".

Comment: @john I don't think it's fair to say that "do" is a meaningless place holder. Like the old adage, "Those who can, do. Those who can't, teach." Or with "how", there's a difference between "How do you throw a football?", asking about the means or method, and "How far can you throw a football?" or "How dare you throw a football?" or other possible verbs. Arguably, "How throw a football?" SHOULD mean the same thing, but no fluent speaker says that. Maybe in that sense "do" is unnecessary surplussage.

Comment: There are several uses of _do_. One (do-support) is meaningless; the Act _do_ of _What I want to do is direct_ is **not** a do-support _do_, as you can tell from the fact that they can be used together: _Did you do it yet?_. The first _do_ is do-support, the second is Act. There are **lots** of uses for auxiliary verbs; some of them are meaningless, like dummy subjects, and others have some semantics. But the constructions determine.

Comment: @Jay: I think John has just nailed the *"meaningless **do**"* question. In questions like *"How do they do that?"*, the first instance has only a "grammatical", not a "semantic" role. As to which proper nouns normally take the definite article, there are only *tendencies* - in any specific case the main determinant is simply *what you hear other people using*. So *"We watch **the** news on **[the]** television to see what's happening in **[The]** Ukraine"*. And even there, some people in some contexts wouldn't bother with *any* of the articles. Usage isn't really very "rule-based" at all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It seems to me that there _are_ rules in those cases, not least of which being that Ukraine is a country and The Ukraine is a region. I don't believe the article can be omitted before "news" in this sentence, and "the television" wouldn't be appropriate if I were referring to multiple sets or the medium in general.

Comment: @Tyler: I think your "country/region" distinction is totally spurious in respect of *"The Ukraine", "The Gambia", "The Sudan", "The Lebanon", "The Argentine", "The Punjab"*, etc. And although Google Books says ***the** news* is ten times more common with the article in my example, that still leaves 10% of writers happy to discard it. And many are [still] happy to include the article before *television* (even more for ***the** radio*), even when they mean the medium in general. You can have your personal preference, but it really is just that - preference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers in the case of Ukraine, the definite article marks a difference (important to some) between a chunk of the USSR and a sovereign nation. Frequency of use doesn't account for situations like “Half of that station's programming is news, half is opinion.” I grant you that there are times when it doesn't matter, but there are plenty of times when it does without coming down to preference.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Hmm, I don't think I've ever heard someone say, "I watched news on television", it's always "the news". Sure you can say, "Half of their programming is news and half is opinion", just like you can say "Half the population is men and half is women", but you still need an article (or suitable adjective) in front of "man" or "woman". To some extent "news" is one of those words that can be countable or uncountable. Like you can say, "I ate the cake", or you can say "I ate cake". Both are valid but mean slightly different things.

Comment: @Jay That is what I'm saying.