# The difference between "How does it work?" and "How it works?"

Tags: questions, interrogatives, subordinate-clauses

Suppose , that I have an object and I am describing *how it works* to other people. Which sentence of the below should I use? Why?

> 1. How does it work?
> 2. How it works?

Please give an explanation.

Comment: Version #1 is an interrogative clause that can be used as a main clause -- that is, as a question, e.g. *"How does it work?"* Version #2 can be used as a subordinate interrogative content clause, e.g. *"Tom  is showing the class how it works."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an iPhone 6, for instance, you can use both the sentences to describe its functionality. However, the approach will be different.

The second sentence does not form a complete question. You require the auxiliary verb *'does'* to do that. But that as a sentence is okay. Let's use both the sentences in concern.

> *"Okay, this is iPhone 6. Now, the first question. How **does** it work?"*

The second sentence is spoken when you directly **tell** that how that device works. There could be various ways you can use this.

> *"...blah...blah...blah... (after explaining the features)...so, this is **how it works."***  OR, 
>   *"I'll tell you how it works."*

Note that there is no question mark in the latter example.

Good explanation is [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17778/how-it-works-vs-how-does-it-work) as Jenz tells in the comment.