# What is the difference between "why are you worried" and "why you are worried"?

Tags: difference, questions

What is the difference between these two sentences?

> Why **are you** worried?
>   Why **you are** worried?

Which one is correct?

Comment: some punctuation would go a long way; also some research - which do you think is correct & why.

Comment: Welcome. Yes, it would really help someone answer your question if it was formatted correctly. Have a look at the edit to see what the changes look like. Secondly, and very importantly, we like to help people learn, so make sure you tell us *exactly* what doubts you have, or what you think the difference between the two sentences might be. We like to help, but we are not a correction service!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["How it works?" vs. "How does it work?"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17778/how-it-works-vs-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you want to know.

> Why are you worried?
>
> ...why you are worried.

The difference is simple. The first sentence is a question. That is also the reason why it contains inversion.

The second one is not a question, but a subclause which is the reason why it is not inverted. It does not form a complete sentence though, since it is only a subclause. A complete sentence would be, for example:

> That is why you are worried.