# Why {you did not / did not you} drink that juice?

Tags: negation, questions-v-relatives

Which of the followings is correct?

> 1) why you did not drink that juice?
>
> 2) why did not you drink that juice?

I think both of them are correct but I don't know which one is more formal! Any further explanations will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Do you have your own guess?  Perhaps based on your knowledge of how to ask questions in English...

Comment: Possible related question ["How it works?" vs. "How does it work?"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17778/how-it-works-vs-how-does-it-work)

Comment: @VictorBazarov: I think both of them are correct! :) but just one of them should be formal.

Comment: In other words, one of them could be OK only *colloquially*.  Which one?  If you can figure that out, then the other one would be the "formal" one, right?

Comment: Yeah! I think we use number (1) more frequently in conversations! :)

Comment: No, that's wrong: #2 is completely ungrammatical, and cannot occur in English. However, the contracted form is legal; only the uncontracted one is illegal.

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't see that why the second option is false!

Comment: @H.R. The second version is not false, it’s wrong.  That’s because *right* does **not** mean *true* — and *wrong* does **not** mean *false*.

Comment: @H.R. It's just not idiomatic. The only "why" is "because we've been voting on it continuously for several hundred years and for the last two hundred years *Why DO not SUBJ VERB* has been voted out of office".

Comment: @StoneyB: So it is true and formal to say: "why did you not drink that juice?"

Comment: It is formally acceptable (as tchrist tells you, we do not use *true* in this sense).

Comment: OK, for god sake! :D I am not an expert! I am just a learner! I really don't make any difference between words like **true** and **right**, **wrong** or **false**! :D

Comment: A very good question. +1 as it helps learn that the contracted version (didn't) is okay.

Comment: @H.R. - on ELL, *right* and *wrong* often refer to grammatical constructs. For example, I can say,  *The biggest ocean in the world is the Atlantic Ocean.* Grammatically, that's correct, but factually, it's false. I can also say, *Pacific Ocean is biggest ocean in world.* Factually, that's true, but grammatically, the sentence is written wrong – it definitely needs some definite articles. So **true** and **false** refer to the accuracy of the statement, while **right** and **wrong** refer to how it's structured.

Answer (score 5):

Neither of the given examples is actually correct (they are both ungrammatical in modern English). The phrase should be either:

> Why did you not drink that juice?

or

> Why didn't you drink that juice?

The first one ("did you not") is the more formal of the two; the contracted form ("didn't you") is much more likely to be heard in conversation.

This has been covered in ELU under the answer to this question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8372/do-you-not-vs-dont-you

Comment: do we use " **didn't** " in formal writing?

Comment: Generally speaking contractions are avoided in formal writing. So you wouldn't normally use  "didn't", for the same reason that you'd avoid "can't", "you're", "wouldn't", etc.

Comment: Are you sure about my both options being false? :)

Comment: @H.R. Note that we don't usually have occasion to ask questions like "Why didn't you drink that juice?" in formal writing.

Comment: @H.R. Neither of your alternatives is correct in standard English.

Comment: would you mind explaining **why** are they incorrect?

Comment: @Jez - I wouldn't say contractions are "generally avoided" in formal writing; I'd say that that are "used more judiciously" in formal writing. See [here](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2006/04/dont_use_contra.html) and [here](http://www.grammar.com/Contractions-Use-in-Formal-Writing) for more thoughts on this. [YD](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/style-and-usage/using-contractions.html) says: _many experts caution against the use of contractions in formal communication. However, this rule does have some flexibility._ Even in formal writing, I'd use "Why didn't you" here.

Comment: @J.R.: I do agree with you! :)