# Which on is correct? "Having said that, why we should select an old job?" or "Having said that, why should we select an old job?"

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct? **"Having said that, why we should select an old job?"** or **"Having said that, why should we select an old job?"**, and why?

Comment: Its pretty simple, the former is a sentence (with a '?!' at the end), that latter, a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sentence contains two clauses:

- The first is a subordinate clause: this is indicated by the fact that its head is a non-finite verb, the participle *having*. It acts as 'supplement', a clause which plays no syntactic role in the main clause: it is not embedded in the main clause but 'anchored' to it by the fact that its subject is taken to be identical with the subject of the main clause.
- The second is the main clause. Of your two choices

  > (1) why should we select an old job?
  >   (2) why we should select an old job?

  only (1) can act as a main clause—specifically, as a question. (2) has no subject/auxiliary inversion so it cannot be taken to be a question; since it is introduced by an interrogative it can only be parsed as [*free relative clause*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/17778/32) (also called a *fused relative clause* or in some circumstances an *embedded question*), which is a subordinate construction and cannot act as a main clause.

The illustration below shows how the whole thing works.

[image: syntax tree]