# Is it "How does my soul taste?" or "How does my soul tastes"?

Tags: phrases

I'm having a debate between my friends and my English teacher, it came up during a practice conversation in class and I said that "How does my soul taste" and they proceeded to correct me by saying that it's said "How does my soul tastes" given the fact that it is referred to as "He/she/it", what is the correct way to say it?

Comment: Well a chef would ask, “How does my ***sole*** taste?”

Comment: Wow. That was a relatively quick way of answering! Thanks @Jim !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In English, there can be only [one conjugated verb](https://www.towson.edu/ows/modulesvagr.htm) that agrees with the subject.

1. *Did* he really eat a dozen chocolate bars at one sitting?
2. She *has* already done her homework.
3. We *were* not consulted on this project.

Your friend's sentence

> *How *does* my sole *tastes*?

would then have two conjugated verbs, which doesn't work in English. It must be:

> How does my sole taste?

I presume you are talking about a type of fish, *sole*, rather than the *soul*.

Comment: Actually did I mean to say soul, it doesn't make sense but it is a translation of a phrase from our language and that's why it's soul.

Comment: OK, but that won't affect subject-verb agreement, so it's the same whether _sole_ or _soul_.

Answer (score 0):

1. How **does** my soul **taste**?
2. How **tastes** my soul?

In the first example, which matches the one given in your question, the [auxiliary verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/do) verb [**does**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/does) is used along with the verb **taste**.

In the second example, which is suggested by your friends' and teacher's understanding of the idea, the auxiliary verb should be omitted, to match the change of form for the verb **tastes**.

To test it:

- He *tastes*. He *does taste*.
- She *tastes*. She *does taste*.
- It *tastes*. It *does taste*.

The use of the auxiliary verb is optional; it's mainly a matter of style and context or emphasis.

See also: ["How it works?" vs "How does it work?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17778/how-it-works-vs-how-does-it-work)