# Where is the girl going or where the girl is going?

Tags: grammar, present-continuous

> Where is the girl going?
> or
> Where the girl is going?

Is/subject/ -ing in present continuous questions
Which one is right according to the Grammer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["How it works?" vs "How does it work?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17778/how-it-works-vs-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 2):

Word order in questions is different from word order in declarative statements.

In a simple declarative statement, we say subject-verb-object, with "helping verbs" following the "is/are". "The girl is going". (Usually we'd follow that with some object or prepositional phrase, like, "The girl is going to work.")

In questions, we say interrogative-to be-subject-helping verb. "Where is the girl going?" "Who was the policeman arresting?" etc.

There are other forms but these are the relevant ones.